# In Visual Studio Code, How To Set File Property to embedded

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I'm building a asp.net core 2.0 web site on a mac and using Visual Studio Code (not Visual Studio). I want to embed a file in my assembly and then read it with code like what is below.

```
       var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        string[] resources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

        using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TestClass.test.txt"))
```

In VS2017, I'd right click on the file and set the file's property to embedded. VS Code does not seem to have a right mouse on a file.

What is the equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add it to the project file, like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="TestClass.test.txt" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I guess this means that in vscode there is no way to do this. I had figured it out by running visual studio in parallels and then it worked with the above. Not a good omen for using vscode w/o visual studio